# is there some way to speed up gparted devices/partitions scanning?

Tags: gparted

I need to work on a single device.

But when I open gparted it wants to scan all the 70+ partitions everywhere (gpt)...

If I try `gparted -help` or --help or help or --pleasehelp, it wont help...

should I patch it?

Answer (score 1):

no, no need to patch.

it is documented in the manual, and it took me more than a 2 decades (I think) to look at the manual:

```
EXAMPLES
       You can run gparted from a command line and specify one or more disk devices.

       For example, to start gparted with the devices /dev/sda and /dev/sdc you would use the following command:

       gparted /dev/sda /dev/sdc
```

it will be much faster now if you just need to work with a single device!